# Using zip in vb.net to send items in pairs from two lists to a console.writeline

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach

I have managed to combine items from two lists of doubles into a list of strings for printing to Console.Writeline:

```
Dim list3 = list1.Zip(Of Double, String)(list2, Function(x, y) x.ToString + vbTab + y.ToString)
For Each n In list3
    Console.WriteLine(n)
Next
```

The preceding lines work fine. However, I was wondering whether I could combine these into one operation. I have tried the following code, which fails to compile:

```
list1.Zip(Of Double, Object)(list2, Sub(x, y) Console.WriteLine(x.ToString + vbTab + y.ToString))
```

I receive the warning that the nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'Func(Of Double, Double, Object)'. If I change the first signature from (of Double, Object) to (of Double, Double, Object), then that fixes the error for the nested sub, but then generates a new error for list1.Zip. I am probably missing something obvious, but I would appreciate it if anyone could guide me to a solution.

NB. I am working with 'Option Infer On'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one and almost certainly more third-party libraries that provide a `ForEach` extension method that you can call directly on an enumerable list.  In the absence of one of those, you can use `Array.ForEach`:

```
Array.ForEach(list1.Zip(list2,
                        Function(x, y) x & vbTab & y).
                    ToArray(),
              Sub(s) Console.WriteLine(s))
```

Notice that I have also simplified your original code from:

```
list1.Zip(Of Double, String)(list2, Function(x, y) x.ToString + vbTab + y.ToString)
```

to:

```
list1.Zip(list2, Function(x, y) x & vbTab & y)
```

There's no need to specify the generic type of the `Zip` method because it can be inferred.  Also, you should ALWAYS use the concatenation operator `&` to concatenate rather than the addition operator `+`.  Doing so means that there's no need to call `ToString` on numbers as concatenation is exclusively performed on `Strings`, so the conversion is built into the operator.  More precisely, the operator is defined that way for the `String` type and the numeric types.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it has taken me so long to mark your response as the answer.